# TDD with AngularJS and Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tdd

I'm trying to use TDD with AngularJS using Protractor (and then Karma for unit test). But simple end-to-end tests just don't work as expected. Here's one case, stripped down to the bare minimum. I want to write a test for the expected repeater, and since it's TDD, the repeater does not yet exist.

I expected/would like to get a "No element found for locator: ..." error, but nothing happened until the test failed with a "Failed: undefined is not a function" error, which is not much help.

How do I put in some reasonable tests and have Protractor give me meaningful responses to guide me through the TDD process? And as a side note, why does Protractor not provide an option to resolve all promises automatically -- that would make testing much more straight-forward, IMO.

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head >
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app/search.js"></script>
  <script src="app/searchCtrl.js"></script>
  <title>Testing TDD & AngularJS</title>

</head>
<body ng-app="search">
  <div ng-controller='searchCtrl'>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchQuery"/>
    <button ng-click="search(searchQuery)" type="submit">search</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-view>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
describe('basic search test', function(){ 
  var searchResults= null;

  beforeEach( function(){ 
    browser.get("/index.html");
    searchResults = element.all(by.repeater('result in results'));
              //    ^-- Expected to get "No element found using locator: xxx"
    searchResults.then(function(results) {
      expect(results.count().toBe(0)}));
              //     ^-- Failed: undefined is not a function
    var searchQueryInput = $('input');
    searchQueryInput.sendKeys('any value');
    var searchButton = element(by.buttonText('search'));
    searchButton.click();
  }); 

  it('has a result', function(){ 
    expect(searchResults.count()).toBe(1);
    ^-- Expected 0 to be 1.
  }); 
});
```